# Various goto implementations in Java

Tags: java, loops, goto

I have a code in c++ with goto statement and would like to know if my Java implementation is correct. Please suggest if there is any other efficient way to get this implemented in JAVA code.

Here is the C++ code with goto statement:

```
bool func( T& d)
{
        retry:
        while(condition1)
        {

                if(condition2)
                {
                        //code
                }
                else
                {
                        w=true;
                        break;

                }
        }
        if(w)
        {
                if(condition3)
                {
                        w=false;
                        //code
                        goto retry;
                }
                else
                {
                        //code
                }
        }
        else
        {
                return false;
        }
}
```

Is this goto implementation correct for JAVA?

Using a labeled while loop

```
public boolean func(T d) {
    boolean w = false;
    int i = 0;

    retry:
    while (true) {
        while (condition1) {
            if (condition2) {
                //code
            } else {
                    //code
                    w = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (w) {
            if (condition3) {
                w = false;
                //code
                continue retry;
            } else {
                // code block 3
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your original C++ code is not valid.

Comment: Why is it not valid?

Comment: Try compiling it.

Comment: I have the implementation in c++ working perfectly fine!

Comment: Try compiling *the code you've posted*.

Comment: corrected the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the first part of your question. From the [Java 17 Language Specification, Chapter 14.7 Labeled Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7):

> Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no goto statement; identifier statement labels are used with break or continue statements (§14.15, §14.16) appearing anywhere within the labeled statement.

But `goto` is a reserved keyword according to the [Chapter 3.9 Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9) from the same document:

> *The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used.*

For the second part: I can't tell you if this is the "correct" translation of a C++ goto into Java, since I would try to avoid labeled statements. In your example you could have written

```java
boolean w = true;
while (w) {
    boolean wInner = true;
    w = condition1;
    while (w && wInner) {
        wInner = condition2;
        if (wInner) {
            //code
        } else {
            //code
        }
        w = condition1;
    }
    if (w) {
        if (condition3) {
            //code
        } else {
            // code block 3
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

I suppose that `condition1`, `condition2` and `condition3` could change their values within the loops, otherwise an even simpler solution should be possible.